# apscheduler doesn't work normally

Tags: python, scheduler

this is the code:

```
#coding=utf-8
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/log', level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

#@sched.interval_schedule(seconds=3)
def job_function():
    logging.debug('hello world')

sched.add_interval_job(job_function, seconds=3)
```

if i switch to decorator, still doesn't work. the log is like this:

```
DEBUG[2011-10-09 11:02:45,175]: Looking for jobs to run
DEBUG[2011-10-09 11:02:45,176]: No jobs; waiting until a job is added
INFO[2011-10-09 11:02:45,176]: Added job "job_function (trigger: interval[0:00:03], next run at: 2011-10-09 11:02:48.176444)" to job store "default"
INFO[2011-10-09 11:02:45,177]: Shutting down thread pool
```

the job `job_function` is added, but is nerver triggered, why?

Comment: found the reason: Jobs are always executed in non-daemonic threads.

Comment: I was not sure about how to log aps calls, this example, helped me! Thank you Izzy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is all your code, then it's clear why it's not working -- the application exits before the job is scheduled to be executed. See the examples provided at https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/tip/examples .

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/modules/scheduler.html#apscheduler.scheduler.Scheduler.start), if you want the Scheduler to block, you need to set the `standalone` flag to `True`.

```
s = Scheduler(standalone=True) 
<add jobs here>
s.start()
```

Make sure you add signal handlers or catch interrupt exceptions :-)